# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R^+}$; prove that if $ab \geqslant 1$, then $a \geqslant 1$ or $b \geqslant 1$

Tags: real-numbers

Is this a valid proof:

We take the contrapositive statement, that if $a < 1$ and $b < 1$, then $ab < 1$, and suppose, to the contrary, that $ab\geqslant 1$. It would follow that
        \begin{align*}
        ab && \geqslant && 1\\
        a && \geqslant && b^{-1}.\\
    \end{align*}
    By definition, however, $b < 1$ implies $b^{-1} > 1$, and we now have $1 \geqslant a \geqslant b^{-1}> 1$, which compresses to $1>1$, providing a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, I think you proof is right.

Comment: Proof is fine but really really indirect.  A bit like making a right turn by doing seven lefts.

Comment: The contrapositive is a great idea.  But if you do it it do a<1 so ab <1b <1.  That's all.

Comment: Proving a contrapositive by contradiction is to assume the initial hypothesis is....true.  so you might as well do a direct proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes, this is a valid proof. However it's very clunky and far more complicated than you need.

- You proceed by contradicting the contrapositive. You could have completely skipped this step, to say that if $0 < a < 1$, $b \ge a^{-1} > 1$.
- There's no need to do contradiction once you've already gotten the contrapositive. If $0 \le a < 1$ and $0 \le b < 1$, then $0 \le ab < 1 \cdot 1 = 1$ and you're already done.

Comment: (+1) Perhaps for beginners, you should insist that it works because $a$ and $b$ are positive..

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how you got to $b=a^{-1}$

Comment: @IzzyM. Because it was a typo.